# All the special characters that need escaping in vim pattern searching/replacment?

Tags: vim

Is there a list of them?
I have a trouble when I want to replace `{inspect.stack()[0][3]}` to `{inspect.stack()[0][3]} called from {inspect.stack()[1][3]}` in my python code. 
And I cannot find a full list from internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `:substitute` (the command)

To do a literal substitution, specify "very-nomagic" [`:help /\V`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5CV) (or escape all special search characters `^$.*[~`) and "case-sensitive" [`/\C`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5CC), and escape the `:substitute` separator (usually `/`) and any backslashes (`\`) in the source. Line breaks must be changed from `^M` to `\n`. Taken together, for the pattern:

```
'\V\C' . substitute(escape(literalPattern, '/\'), "\n", '\\n', 'ge')
```

In the replacement, `&` and `~` must be escaped (in addition to `/` and `\`) if the [`'magic'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27magic%27) option is set. (`\V` doesn't work here). Cp. [`:help sub-replace-special`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-special)

```
escape(literalReplacement, '/\' . (&magic ? '&~' : ''))
```

#### `substitute()` (the function)

Something similar applies to [`substitute()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29) as well; `&` must always be escaped, as `'magic'` is always set, and only `~` must not be escaped:

```
substitute(input, '\V\C' . escape(literalPattern, '\'), escape(literalReplacement, '\&')), 'g')
```